# How to use own ContentProvider to other application?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have created a my own ContentProvider by extending class ContentProvider with all its abstract methods.

I am able to use MyContentProivder in my application where I created it,but I
am not getting how can I use it in other application.

This question might have been asked many times but I am really not getting any information.

Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your Custom ContentProvider you can use it in other application with its URI.

To insert,

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("title", "lalit");
        values.put("isbn", "0470285818");        
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(URI), values);
```

To read,

```
        Uri allTitles = Uri.parse(URI);
        Cursor c = managedQuery(allTitles, null, null, null, null);
```

In the same way you can delete, update using query.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer it is working but how can other application can know what are the names of columns in Provider's table.